# How to set child view controller as parent?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview, childviewcontroller

I have a collection cell.If am click any cell need to go another view controller.

```
switch (indexPath.row) {
            case 2:
        {
            ElectricianVC *elec=[[ElectricianVC alloc]init];
           elec =[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Electrician"];
           [self addChildViewController:elec];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:elec animated:YES];
            [self presentViewController:elec animated:YES completion:Nil];
            NSLog(@"electritianvc");
        }
```

My parent view controller is collection view controller and it have navigation controller.is there any thing wrong in the code please help me friends.
Error
Application tried to present modally an active controller

Comment: Why don't you use segues? That should do everything you need automatically.

Comment: don't use storyboard

Comment: try only one line `[self.navigationController pushViewController:elec animated:YES];`

Comment: yes am trying to achieve that  @LalitKumar

Comment: please edit your question.

Comment: why are you presenting the view controller after pushing it? you should do only one thing,either push it or present it

Comment: read the coding first T_77

Comment: yes i read the question. Tell me why are you doing pushing and presenting?

Comment: I have navigation view controller in root view controller

Comment: also you need to mention log reports and crash reports if they occur.Atleast you need to tell us which part is not working.

Comment: Oh yes thanks for your suggestion I will update my error report

Comment: please remove the uicollectionview tag. It has nothing to do with the code.

Answer (score 0):

Use following code

```
switch (indexPath.row) {
            case 2:
        {
            ElectricianVC *elec=[[ElectricianVC alloc]init];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:elec animated:YES];

            NSLog(@"electritianvc");
        }
```

Comment: lalit i tried before this is working, but i like to add my view controller as a child view controller.

Comment: help me to add this as a child view controller

Comment: add this line too `[self addChildViewController:elec];`

Comment: Application tried to present modally an active controller <collection>

Comment: why you want to add as child view controller

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84569/discussion-between-kishore-kumar-and-lalit-kumar).